# How to solve this integral over the specific curve and region?

Tags: integration, calculus

Integrate the general expression
$$\int_{x0}^x \int_{y0}^y  \frac{\nabla^{2}\Lambda (\chi ',\psi ')}{\nabla\psi '\nabla\chi '}\nabla\chi '\nabla\psi '$$ in the curve from $(x0,y0)\to(x0,y)\to(x,y)$, working with the function $\Lambda (\chi ',\psi ')$ in the general form and not by replacing it with an arbitrary function of your choice (see figure)

[image]

Comment: I tried transcribing your equation, but you seem to missing the differentials (presumably $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$, judging by the limits).

Comment: Please fix the notation and explain why this has something to do with physics.